# Is `inline;` an invalid declaration or not a declaration at all?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, declaration, standards

Say I want to know what is a declaration. I go to [[dcl.pre]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre) and read that

> Declarations have the form

followed by various possible forms, one of which is a [*simple-declaration*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:simple-declaration), which can, in turn, have the form of *decl-specifier-seq init-declarator-list(opt)`;`*. given the latter piece is optional, I assume a *simple-declaration* can have the form of just *decl-specifier-seq`;`*. By the same reasoning, I end up understanding that a [*decl-specifier-seq*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.general#nt:decl-specifier-seq) can have the form of a single [*decl-specifier*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.general#nt:decl-specifier); finally, this can be just `inline`.

If the above reasoning is correct, then I conclude that a line of code containing just `inline;` is a declaration. But clearly it is not even compilable.

What does this mean? That `inline;` *is* a declaration but is an invalid declaration? And that I should understand that from the text? Or what?

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#5.sentence-1?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer, so it's not a declaration at all, and document doesn't provide a link from the parts i linked to that parts you linked, so reading everything is the only way. I guess it would become a messy need with an enormous amount of connections, ahahah.

Comment: _document doesn't provide a link from the parts i linked to that parts you linked_ You linked [dcl.pre], I linked [dcl.pre]

Comment: There is no formal difference between "not a declaration" and "an invalid declaration".

Comment: @LanguageLawyer, I was implying that on the right of the first line under [_simple-declaration_](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:simple-declaration) there could be a link to [5](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#5), plus to all other places where [_simple-declaration_](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:simple-declaration) is referred to. But this, as I said, probably means an extremely dense graph. Well, it wouldn't even be useful if all it does is linking to numbers, which one don't know what they are about without inspecting them one by one. Never mind.

Comment: well this is like `inline inline int x=1;` is not a valid declaration although allows by syntax.

Comment: or like the rules "you cannot use undeclared variable", the behavior is undefined" and so on which is almost not possible (or feasible) to define in syntax

Answer (score 3):

Lots of things satisfy the grammar but are nonsense:

```
int int int i;
1+1+=1;
void(1,2);
*1;
int &*pr;
(1+...);
void f(consteval int);
inline struct S {};
++main;
```

The proper response to these oddities is not to worry about what they platonically are; the proper response is **wat**.

Answer (score 2):

From [[gram.general]](http://eel.is/c++draft/gram.general) (my emphasis)

> This summary of C++ grammar is intended to be an aid to comprehension. It is not an exact statement of the language. In particular, **the grammar described here accepts a superset of valid C++ constructs**.